# How do you pass a queue reference to a function in another file through a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, import, queue

in importreftest.py

```
import importreftest2
import Queue
import threading

q= Queue.Queue(maxsize=0)

q.put(1)
q.put(2)
q.put("hello")

print "here"

t = threading.Thread(target = importreftest2.trythis, args = q)
t.start()
```

in importreftest2.py

```
def trythis(q):
    print "trythis"
    while True:
        if not q.empty():
            print q.get()
```

When running importreftest.py "trythis" is not printed, nor is anything in the queue

Comment: When I run this code, I get, "trythis() argument after * must be a sequence, not instance".  When that is fixed, I get everything printed, and then an unstoppable program because trythis is in a tight loop.  Maybe show your actual code?

Comment: `args = q` needs to be `args = (q,)`.